# Question for moderators (Ask Ubuntu Clean UP)

Tags: discussion, cleanup

During the Ask Ubuntu Clean UP campaign I have run out of my allotment of flags. Must I wait 24 hrs to receive more? Moderators?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you have to wait until midnight UTC to get more flags.

**however**, there is another option - mainly, you can join the [Ubuntu Regulators Chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/206/ubuntu-regulators) and drop questions in need of closing in there - currently, we have three moderators lurking there, as well as other community members.

Comment: Not an acceptable answer. Thanks for the chatroom hint.

Comment: Unfortunately, that **is** the answer.

Comment: I suppose setting limits keeps specific users from pestering the staff too much. I work on a busy forms, and although we appreciate the input from the community, there is such a thing as "too much of a good thing"

Comment: Not even that, it's more to tell a user to slow down and take a break.

Comment: Oi watch where your swinging that hammer James ;)

Comment: @Allan wonderful sense of humor there, would be a shame if something were to happen to the person who owns it... ;)